# Menupop convertir en array Multidimencional php

Tags: php, array

Mediante un REGEX en preg_macht_all consigo leer una HTML que tiene un MENUPOP con el fin de lograr un cruce de valores mi meta es optener una lista como esta, pero por mas que he jugado con el foreach no logro este reporte. Me puede alguien dar una mano para lograr esto.

CASO#1:http://LocalHost?id=495:Id 495

CASO#1:http://LocalHost?id=191:Id 191

CASO#1:http://LocalHost?id=598:Id 598

CASO#2:http://LocalHost?id=301:Id 301

CASO#2:http://LocalHost?id=302:Id 302

CASO#2:http://LocalHost?id=303:Id 303

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CASO#1
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => CASO#2
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => http://LocalHost?id=495
            [2] => http://LocalHost?id=191
            [3] => http://LocalHost?id=598
            [4] => 
            [5] => http://LocalHost?id=301
            [6] => http://LocalHost?id=302
            [7] => http://LocalHost?id=303
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Id 495
            [2] => Id 191
            [3] => Id 598
            [4] => 
            [5] => Id 301
            [6] => Id 302
            [7] => Id 303
        )

)
```

Con esta combinacion foreach logro llamarlo pero me repite CASO#1 nunca cambia a CASO#2

```
            foreach ($hexa[1] as $match_groups){
                
                foreach ($hexa[2] as $match_url){
                    if(empty($match_groups)){break;};
                        echo $match_groups;
                        echo $match_url."\n";   
                    foreach ($hexa[3] as $match_name){
                        echo $match_name;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: sube un ejemplo de como estas tratando de solucionar tu problema y que resultado obtienes de dicho ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que estás buscando, lo que hago es recorrer $hexa[1] y en cada iteración, si encuentro un caso lo guardo para las siguientes iteraciones, si está vacio hago el echo.

```
<?php

$casoActual = '';

foreach($hexa[1] as $llave => $caso) {
    if(! empty($caso)) {
        $casoActual = $caso;
    } else {
        echo $casoActual . ":" . $hexa[2][$llave] . ":" . $hexa[3][$llave] . "<br/>";
    }
}

?>
```

Salida:

```
CASO#1:http://LocalHost?id=495:Id 495 
CASO#1:http://LocalHost?id=191:Id 191 
CASO#1:http://LocalHost?id=598:Id 598 
CASO#2:http://LocalHost?id=301:Id 301 
CASO#2:http://LocalHost?id=302:Id 302 
CASO#2:http://LocalHost?id=303:Id 303
```